# Neo Children Output

Tags: matrix

I have a Neo Field: I want to work with blocks up to 3 levels deep.

My output code works fine:

```
{% nav block in entry.myField.level(1) %}
    {% switch block.type.handle %}
        {% case 'title' %}
            <h2>{{ block.title }}</h2>

        {% case 'blocks' %}
             {% for item in block.children %}
                 {% include "_includes/elements/" ~ item.type %}
             {% endfor %}

    {% endswitch %}
{% endnav %}
```

But how can I output the deeper block levels? 
I don't find any way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You take the same approach as the original child.

So you'd nest a `{% for 3rdChild in item.children %}` in your `{% for item in block.children %}`

Answer (score 1):

Not tested – I've no idea if the [`{% nav %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/nav) tag even works properly with Neo, but assuming it does, you're not actually rendering the children for each `block` with your current code. This might do it:

```
{% nav block in entry.myField.level(1) %}

    {% switch block.type.handle %}

        {% case 'title' %}
            <h2>{{ block.title }}</h2>

        {% case 'blocks' %}
            {% for item in block.children %}
                {% include "_includes/elements/" ~ item.type %}
             {% endfor %}

    {% endswitch %}

    {% ifchildren %}
        {% children %}
    {% endifchildren %}

{% endnav %}
```